# Firestore ClassNotFoundException: com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials and com/google/api/client/googleapis/util/Utils

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have a gradle project in Intellij where I am trying to access the Firestore database by following the guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup but it throws ClassNotFoundException for google-oauth2 GoogleCredentials and in FirebaseOptions$Builder for google-api Utils.

Following is my code.

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(googleCredentials)
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

But that throws ClassNotFoundException for com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials

```
com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials
at com.amazon.asksdk.roomservice.data.DatabaseInitializer.initialize(DatabaseInitializer.java:36)
at com.amazon.asksdk.roomservice.data.TasksDAO.<init>(TasksDAO.java:28)
at com.amazon.asksdk.roomservice.RoomServiceSpeechlet.onSessionStarted(RoomServiceSpeechlet.java:54)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestDispatcher.dispatchSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestDispatcher.java:112)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.internalHandleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:152)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.handleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:115)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.lambda.SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

And writing it like this:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Throws exception in FirebaseOptions$Builder for googleapis Utils

```
com/google/api/client/googleapis/util/Utils: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/util/Utils
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.<init>(FirebaseOptions.java:197)
at com.amazon.asksdk.roomservice.data.DatabaseInitializer.initialize(DatabaseInitializer.java:45)
at com.amazon.asksdk.roomservice.data.TasksDAO.<init>(TasksDAO.java:28)
at com.amazon.asksdk.roomservice.RoomServiceSpeechlet.onSessionStarted(RoomServiceSpeechlet.java:54)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestDispatcher.dispatchSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestDispatcher.java:112)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.internalHandleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:152)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.handleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:115)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.lambda.SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 8 more
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazon.alexa:alexa-skills-kit:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.9.40'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.0.0'

    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.0.6.v20130930'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.0.6.v20130930'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10'
}
```

How do I resolve this since gradle should be taking care of the correct dependencies by itself? I have tried explicitly adding the following but that didn't work:

```
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-servlet:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
```

I also see these in the External Libraries. I am trying to run this project by AWS lambda, so I upload the jar to lambda to eventually run this.

Comment: I tried to make a mvn project, imported the same dependencies at it worked like a charm. Not a single change in the code, just switched from gradle to mvn and it worked. I am confused...

Comment: Converting to maven to fix this does not seem to be a proper solution, have you fixed this issue by keeping the Gradle build tool intact?